# How do you implement compareTo methods cleanly?

Tags: java, comparable

Currently I am writing a compareTo method for quadratic functions in the form: ax^2 + bx + c.

a, b, c are integer coefficients that are passed to the class through the constructor.

In the compareTo method, I am supposed to first compare the a-coefficients between two functions, but if they are equal, I compare the b-coefficients. If the b's are equal, I compare the c's.

The method that I came up for this ended up being pretty ugly:

```
public int compareTo(QuadraticFunction other)
{
    if (a > other.a)
        return 1;
    else if (a < other.a)
        return -1;
    else if (b > other.b)
        return 1;
    else if (b < other.b)
        return -1;
    else if (c > other.c)
        return 1;
    else if (c < other.c)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

So I was wondering, if you have these "tiered" systems of comparisons (like compare a's before b's before c's), what's the best way to implement them? I can't imagine writing a method like mine if you have to go through 10+ variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an arbitrary number of coefficients (all of the same type), you should store them in a `List` (or something similar), rather than individually-named member variables.  That allows you to convert your example code into an iteration.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: That's correct.  But I think it's fairly safe to assume that one would represent polynomial coefficients with homogeneous types.

Comment: Agreed, but the caveat should be mentioned for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

The [Guava Libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provide an extremely nice tool to do this called [ComparisonChain](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html).

Your code would look something like this:

```
import com.google.common.base.ComparisonChain;
...
public int compareTo(QuadraticFunction other) {
  return ComparisonChain.start()
    .compare(a, other.a)
    .compare(b, other.b)
    .compare(c, other.c)
    .result();
}
```

Comment: Would new Java8 `Comparator` API warrant its own answer, or should we maybe merge it there?

Answer (score 1):

For readability, and to use the built-in compare methods for a, b, c, I would refactor to this:

```
public int compareTo(QuadraticFunction other) {
    if (a.equals(other.a)) {
        if (b.equals(other.b))
            return c.compareTo(other.c);
        return b.comapreTo(other.b);
    }
    return a.compareTo(other.a);
}
```

This code assumes the fields are `Number`. If they are a primitive, either convert them to wrapped type or change `a.equals(b) to`a == b`and change`a.compareTo(b)`to`a - b`.

Also note that when an `if` returns, there is never a need for an `else` - it's redundant, so remove it.

Comment: One could argue that retaining the `else` facilitates refactoring.  In the OP's case, (s)he might later decide to change the code to `if (cond1) { retval = 1; } else if (cond2) { retval = -1; } else ... return retval;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an idiom like the below which breaks the comparison into clear sections by field, only requires one test per field, and uses the [`signum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#signum%28long%29) method to produce the return values.

Note, the subtraction below works for `int`, `short`, `char`, or `byte` fields.
For `long`, `float`, and `double` fields you have to use separate checks for `<` and `==` to avoid overflow/underflow, and loss of precision due to rounding.  Be careful of `NaN` too when comparing floating point values.
For `Comparable` fields, you can just set delta to the result of `compareTo` after using separate conditions to handle `null`.

```
long delta = ((long) a.field1) - b.field1;
if (delta != 0) { return Long.signum(delta); }

delta = ((long) a.field2) - b.field2;
if (delta != 0) { return Long.signum(delta); }

...

return 0;
```

Comment: That will only work correctly if `a.field1` and co are at most integers.

Comment: @Voo, true.  The OP says "a, b, c are integer coefficients".

Comment: Ah while reading the question I interpreted "integer coefficient" in the mathematical sense of the word, but yes it's probably more likely he really meant integer int. Still I think a big fat warning is important when using this idiom is always in place: It's been misused for decades so I'm a bit wary with it.

Comment: @Voo, Fair enough, added a caveat.